# dsn less connection not working for java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I am trying to connect my .accdb database to my java application here .
I have kept the database in same directory.
I have used all possible solutions but its not of any use.
Application works fine when i connect it through DSN. but i want to establish a connection dsn less.
is there any solution?
Thanks in advance
here is my code:

```
String database="Service_Center.accdb";
String url="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ="+database+"";
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");      
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
//Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Service_Center","","");
String sql="Select Sr_No,Call_Date,Source,RMA_No,Item_name,Booking_Desc,Customer_name,Customer_address,Customer_contact,Call_Status From RMA_Master Where MaterialRequireStatus='"+materialStatus+"'";
PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();    
table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));  
rs.close();
pst.close();
con.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ODBC driver name is malformed because it is missing a couple of spaces. The correct driver name is

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}
```